# The empty path didn't match any of these URLs

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-urls, django-apps

Using the URLconf defined in `first_project.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^$ [name='index']
admin/
```

The empty path didn't match any of these.

This is code in urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from first_app import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('^$',views.index,name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#path) should not have regex characters in it, you are confusing it with [`url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#url)/[`re_path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#re-path) syntax

```
path('',views.index,name='index')
```